# Getting the "Arguments are of the wrong type..." exception just by assigning query text

Tags: mysql, delphi

I have downloaded and installed MySQL Connector 5.1 x64 so I can use MySQL with Delphi. I can make connection with ODBC and do a connection from my Delphi environment and from MySQL Workbench.

But, when I build my Query at runtime, I get an error saying:

> Project AAA.exe raised exception class EOleException with message 'Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.

My code:

```
qDates := TADOQuery.Create(Component);
qDates.Connection := FConnection;
qDates.SQL.Text :=
  'select ' +
  '  * ' +
  'from ' +
  '  resulttable ' +
  'where ' +
  '  oid = :oid ' +
  '  and datedial >= :datebegin and datedial <= :dateend'; // <<-- Exception here
```

Details:
The exception happens right on the text assignment, before I have a chance to configure parameters.
If I comment out the `where` clause the assignment goes fine.
This is similar to [Using parameters with ADO Query (mysql/MyConnector)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826210/using-parameters-with-ado-query-mysql-myconnector) but the difference is that I assign whole text at once and I get the exception before I have a chance to configure parameters.

The puzzling part - exact same code works fine on my other machine, but I can not figure out what is different.

Hence the question - what could cause the above exception outside of the Delphi code and MySQL server?

Comment: *I can not figure out what is different.* What about connection strings ? Do not they differ in something related to parameters ?

Comment: Connection strings are exactly the same (and the source code is exactly the same too). The only major difference is OS - WinXPSP3x86 vs Win7x64

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on the PC standing next to my own! xD Hence the question. Not a duplicate because the exception occurs before `Parameters` and SQL query is set at once.

Comment: @whosrdaddy: I have tried this, and this helped. Can you post that as an answer? I would appreciate if you remove the duplicate vote, because the questions are different (yet have similar parts and solution).

Comment: Small question, what delphi version are you using?

Comment: @whosrdaddy: Delphi-xe2. Should I add that tag to the question?

Comment: It never hurts, but in this case it seems this problem has never been solved in later versions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a quirk with the MySQL ODBC provider.

If you assign the connection after setting the SQL text, then it will work.
The reason why can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26506278/800214).

```
qDates := TADOQuery.Create(Component);
// do net yet assign TADOConnection to prevent roundtrip to ODBC provider
qDates.SQL.Text :=
  'select ' +
  '  * ' +
  'from ' +
  '  resulttable ' +
  'where ' +
  '  oid = :oid ' +
  '  and datedial >= :datebegin and datedial <= :dateend';
qDates.Connection := FConnection;
```

**UPDATE**

This [QC entry](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=107267) explains the exact reason for this problem.

In short, the ADODB unit, patch this line from the `RefreshFromOleDB` procedure :

```
      Parameter.Attributes := dwFlags and $FFFFFFF0; { Mask out Input/Output flags }
```

To:

```
if dwFlags and $FFFFFFF0 <= adParamSigned + adParamNullable + adParamLong then
 Parameter.Attributes := dwFlags and $FFFFFFF0; { Mask out Input/Output flags }
```